# how to Use a variable that we imported from parent component with @input in the child html component using {{ }}

Tags: angular, output, components

this is my child component .ts file :

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import { IProduct } from '../product/produit';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-zoomdetails',
  templateUrl: './zoomdetails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./zoomdetails.component.css']
})
export class ZoomdetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  **@Input() produit : String;**
}
```

and this is where i want to use the 'produit' variable

```
      <div class="col-md-6" style="border:0px solid rgba(163, 152, 152, 0.856)">
        <span class="pull-right">
        <!-- Datos del vendedor y titulo del producto -->
        ***<h1>{{produit}} </h1>***    
        <h4 style="color:#337ab7"> Daniel Keyes <small style="color:#337ab7">(50 ventes)</small></h4>
```

Any Help plzzzzz

Comment: could you add and exemple of <app-zoomdetails ...> utilisation ? Like excerpt of the parent component template and logic ?

Comment: @PierreMallet i have 2 components one is <product>  and the other is <zoom-details> so when i click on a product component i want to pass the data from <product> to <zoom-details> ( zoom details component is a modal where the data of a specific product are displayed)

Comment: so i use @input to pass the data from <product> to zoomdetails.ts but i can not display that data in zoomdetails.html with the the double brackets {{ }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the value of produit from parent component with the below code. you can also see the [sample here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-child-interaction)

Parent component TS file

```
export class AppComponent  {
  //passing values from parent to child
  produit = "child";          
}
```

Parent component HTML template - below is the child tag

```
<app-zoomdetails [produit]=produit ></app-zoomdetails>
```

Child component HTML template

```
<input type="textbox" [(ngModel)]='produit'>
```

Comment: thanks for your help but my problem is not how to pass data from parent to child because i already did that with the @input and it does work

Comment: but the problem is that i can 't use @input variable that i imported from the parent.html to the child.ts in the child html file :/

Comment: is the HTML you shared is child template or parent template?

Comment: it s the child template

Comment: if you send the value value for produit from parent component properly it will display with interpolation {{}} properly. Also you don't need to click from parent component to send the data